# How do you mod an internally geared hub to permanently run in one gear?

Tags: brakes, internally-geared-hub, coaster

This is nowhere near a priority for me. But I fixed my first coaster brake, I'm high off my success and I want to learn more.

Comment: I know far from an answer, but why?  What purpose would a single speed internally geared hub serve?

Comment: IGHs tend to be desirable items.  You might sell the wheel and buy a more-suitable donor, and even end up ahead financially.

Answer (score 7):

If you really wanted to, or if you were forced to do so because of a broken shifter or hub, you could do it by taking the cable and removing it from the shifter, then running it directly into wherever the housing stop is before the hub, such that the cable head is sitting in the housing stop. You'd then clamp the cable to the bell crank or cassette joint, or whatever the particular hub has, such that it's set in the gear you choose. You could use the barrel adjuster to tune it.